# When user searches in input box, redirect to a different page

Tags: php, html

I have an input box, which searches a database for the inputted text and displays the information on the page where the input box is.

Is it possible for once the user has typed in text in the input box and clicked submit, it redirects them to **page.php** and displays the results on page.php?

```
$getUsers = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Users");
$numUsers = mysql_num_rows($getUsers);
$Online = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE  $now < expireTime");
$Online = mysql_num_rows($Online);
echo"
<div class='members-browse-page'>
<div style='width: 876px; height: 28px; margin-bottom: 10px; clear: both;'>
<span class='form-label' style='margin-right: 30px;padding-top:5px;'>
<strong>Search:</strong>
</span>
<span>
<span class='search-bar'>
<form action='' method='POST' style='margin:0;padding:0;'>
<input type='text' name='UserSearchBar' maxlength='100' style='width:400px;'>
<input type='submit' name='UserSearchSubmit' value='Search Users'>
<a href='online.aspx'><b>Online (".$Online.")</b></a>
</form>
</span>
</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Note: The `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, they have been removed from PHP 7, your code will stop working when you upgrade to that version. You should not write new code using them, use [`mysqli_*` or PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) instead.

Comment: Next on my list to do!

Comment: Not an answer but a comment. LOTS of inline styling in there - best to have an external CSS with the styles rather than inline - makes for better code structure. Its one thing I struggle with because when I was learning - its what we were taught to do, but it makes the code very messy and often leads to duplicate styling rules. Just a thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple Give action to your form

```
<form action='yourpage.php' method='POST' style='margin:0;padding:0;'>
```

Comment: @TheCodesee if its helped you please try to vote in +1

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action='page.php' method='POST' style='margin:0;padding:0;'>
```

Just write page.php in form action. you can get search box value on page.php using $_POST method. like `$_POST['UserSearchBar']`. Use this post value or write appropriate code for it and display result.